# How to fix TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' in linearsvc.score()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svc

The last step in my pipeline is a `linearsvc()` classifier. I am using the same pipeline for training and scoring. So the datatype conversion should be the same in both the cases.

I am getting the below error when I run

```
pipeline.score(X_test, y_truth)
```

Error log:

```
    return self.model.score(X, y)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py", line 116, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 602, in score
    return self.steps[-1][-1].score(Xt, y, **score_params)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 357, in score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 176, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 72, in _check_targets
    type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
  File "lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 287, in type_of_target
    if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
  File "lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 264, in unique
    ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
  File "lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 312, in _unique1d
    ar.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: The traceback is pretty obvious, change whichever of those 2 variables that is a string to a float

Comment: I am using the same pipeline for training and scoring. So the datatype conversion should be the same in both the cases.